# Sprites appearing huge after refresh of iphone app in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I was writing a simple app for iphone(my first) and i was running into a problem that i could not seem to solve and couldn't find anyone else with a similar issue. It is as follows i restart the GameScene and after it refreshes when the player is killed everything on the screen appears big i have the code and screenshots below.

```
func goToGameScene(){
    self.removeAllChildren()
    self.scene?.removeFromParent()
    let gameScene:GameScene = GameScene(size: self.view!.bounds.size) // create your new scene
    let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1.0) // create type of transition (you can check in documentation for more transtions)
    gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.fill
    self.view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
}
```

[How it looks for the first time running it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhN0D.jpg)

[After Refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQFsL.jpg)

Comment: Does this same code run on the very first load?

Comment: @kid_x no it only runs when you die, should i set it to run at the start of the game?

Comment: You should at least verify that the scene as you create it initially is the same as the one you create after dying.  I think your GameScene size might be different, which in turn would cause your sprites to look larger.

Comment: SKScene size doesn't necessarily correspond to the bounds of the view that contains it.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going with the default template and loading from an SKS file your Scene may not be the same size as your View. I would recommend using your current scene size instead of the view. Also wouldn't hurt to use the same aspect mode too.

```
let gameScene:GameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
gameScene.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
```

Of course I am assuming self is the SKScene.